# Using .toObject with Generic classes in Firestore to get POJO from DocumentSnapshot

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Firebase Realtime Database there is support for deserialising objects using GenericTypeIndicator. Can someone shed light on how to do the same with Firestore ?

I have a document snapshot which I want to convert to a POJO which is parametrised.

This is the error it throws when I try to do that

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Class com.thesportsbeing.thesportsbeing.screens.festadmin.eventslist.eventadmin.scoring.MatchScore has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead.
```

The problem is there is no GenericTypeIndicator in the firestore package, it is present in the realtime-database package. Any workarounds ? or something to get things done would be great.

MyClass is similiar to this

```
public class MyClass<R extends SomeAbstractClass> {
    R someClassWhichExtendsAboveAbstractClass;
}
```

Comment: any solution for this ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a discussion of the issue and workarounds:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/222

Easiest way is to declare a subclass of your generic class:

```
class MyNonGeneric extends MyClass<R> {}

// Usage
snapshot.toObject(MyNonGeneric.class);
```

Alternatively need get each top level property of the POJO separately and cast it.